Automating API tests with C#
Trying to go from manually testing to automating API tests. Choosen to write the tests in C# and installed the following packages: Nunit, NUnit3TestAdapter, NewtonSoft.Json, Fluent Assertions and RestSharp. The only problem is getting acces with a Bearer token I don't know how, can somebody help with this?
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using RestSharp;
using FluentAssertions;

namespace AutoTest1.TestFixtures
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ApiTests
    {
        private const string TokenUrl = "https://testapi.com/token";
        private const string ClientId = "123456789";
        private const string ClientSecret = "1000222";

        [Test]
        public async Task Test_ApiAuthentication()
        {
            var token = await GetBearerTokenAsync(TokenUrl, ClientId, ClientSecret);
            token.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty("Token should be retrieved successfully");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                var responseContent = await MakeAuthenticatedRequestAsync(ApiUrl, token);
                responseContent.Should().NotBeNull("Response content should be received");
                Console.WriteLine($"API Response: {responseContent}");
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task TokenRetrieval()
        {
            var token = await GetBearerTokenAsync(TokenUrl, ClientId, ClientSecret);
            token.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty("Token should be retrieved successfully");
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetBearerTokenAsync(string tokenUrl, string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(tokenUrl);
            var request = new RestRequest();
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
            request.AddParameter("client_id", clientId);
            request.AddParameter("client_secret", clientSecret);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.Method = Method.Post;

            var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

            if (response.IsSuccessful)
            {
                var json = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
                return json["access_token"]?.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.StatusCode} - {response.StatusDescription}");
                return null;
            }
        }

        private static async Task<string> MakeAuthenticatedRequestAsync(string apiUrl, string token)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(apiUrl);
            var request = new RestRequest();
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
            request.Method = Method.Get;

            var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

            if (response.IsSuccessful)
            {
                return response.Content;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.StatusCode} - {response.StatusDescription}");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}


I searched the web and asked chat but didn't got much. Followed some instructions but unfortunate it doesn't work

FYI - Don't assume that just because the response content is not null or empty that the request was successful. You should be checking the response's status code.

I assume you're getting a compilation error at request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}"); because token is not defined.
You probably want a little helper method that can use an existing value or retrieve a new one.
private string? bearerToken;

private async Task<string?> GetBearerToken()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(bearerToken))
    {
        bearerToken = await GetBearerTokenAsync(TokenUrl, ClientId, ClientSecret);
    }

    return bearerToken;
};

If the tests are going to be long running it may be that the bearer token becomes invalid and you'll have to add some additional logic to very the token is still valid and refresh it if necessary.
